# JIT debugging PHP in Aptana Studio

Tags: php, xdebug, jit, chromium, aptana3

Linux Mint 15, Aptana Studio 3.4.1, Chromium 28.0.1500.71

Sorry, this is a little lengthy to explain. Please let me know if something's not clear.

The title is my goal. I have a local server set up with Apache2. I don't know if it matters, but I have dnsmasq set up to redirect, for example, site.dev/index.html to /home/wastvedt/Projects/site/www/index.html ([described here](http://daniel.hahler.de/easy-dns-wildcard-setup-for-local-domains-using-dnsmasq)).

I've followed the tutorials I can find. XDebug is running, I have the helper installed in Chromium, and the debugger, interpreter, and web server set up in Aptana.

I'm working on a WordPress site and want to break on one of the functions in my theme's functions.php file. I created a breakpoint in the function in Aptana, turned on the XDebug helper in Chromium, and updated a post, which calls the function in question. Aptana recognizes what I'm doing and prompts me with the option of breaking on the first line. Regardless of what I select, I see "XDebug JIT Session [Remote Launch]" in the Debug view. The prompt appears three times, but nothing else happens in Aptana.

I think the problem might have something to do with linking files in the editor to files in Apache. When I try this JIT debugging thing with "localhost" (located at /home/wastvedt/apache2/www/index.php), Aptana brings up /home/wastvedt/Projects/site/www/index.php. This isn't right, but maybe the real problem is somewhere else. To be honest I'm a little lost now.

Any thoughts? I'd provide some sort of dump or output, but I'm not sure which or what.

Thanks for reading,
Trygve

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly setup XDebug with Aptana I setup the below options by going to the Window menu -> Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Editors -> PHP -> Debug:

Allow multiple debug sessions: Always
Break on first line when an unknown remote sessions (JIT): Never

Then click on XDebug in Installed Debuggers -> Configure:

Use Multisession: OFF
Accept remote session (JIT): any

That pretty much made it work for me.